Map Dataframe Column Values Based on Two Dictionaries Conditionally
I have a dataframe df_test. I want to map the column color conditionally:

if category is 'tv', then map using the tv_map dictionary
else map using the radio_map dictionary

I could split df_test by category, map each dictionary, then row bind but I would like to do it in one-go something like:
df_test['new_col'] = df_test.apply(lambda x: tv_map.get(x, x) if x['category'] == "tv" else color_map.get(x, x), axis=1)

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': ['tv', 'radio', 'tv', 'radio'],
    'color': ['red', 'green', 'green', 'red']
    })

tv_map = {'red': 'tv_red', 'green': 'tv_green'}
radio_map = {'red': 'radio_red', 'green': 'radio_green'}

df_test['new_col'] = df_test.query('category == "tv"')['color'].map(tv_map)
df_test['new_col'] = df_test.query('category == "radio"')['color'].map(radio_map)
df_test


Let's use np.where:
df_test['new_col'] = np.where(df_test['category'].eq('tv'),
                              df_test['color'].map(tv_map), 
                              df_test['color'].map(radio_map))

Output:
  category  color      new_col
0       tv    red       tv_red
1    radio  green  radio_green
2       tv  green     tv_green
3    radio    red    radio_red


This will do the trick:
df_test.loc[df_test.category.eq("tv"), "new_col"] = df_test.loc[df_test.category.eq("tv"), "color"].map(tv_map)
df_test.loc[df_test.category.eq("radio"), "new_col"] = df_test.loc[df_test.category.eq("radio"), "color"].map(radio_map)

output:
  category  color      new_col
0       tv    red       tv_red
1    radio  green  radio_green
2       tv  green     tv_green
3    radio    red    radio_red

